# Error when trying to cross-compile C++ code for Ubuntu 18.04 and ARM Cortex-A9

Tags: c++, arm, g++, cross-compiling, vivado

I am currently trying to cross-compile code from a GitHub project for my Ubuntu 18.04. distribution and the ARM Cortex-A9 processor on a Xilinx Zedboard. Unfortunately, when executing the automatically generated Makefile, I run into an error that I have a hard time interpreting.

This is the console output:

```
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/driver.dir/library/driver/platform-xlnk.cpp.o
[ 40%] Linking CXX static library libdriver.a
[ 40%] Built target driver
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hw-asr-W2A2-ocr-pynq.dir/library/host/input_handling.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.1/include/hls_half.h:44:0,
                 from /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.1/include/etc/ap_private.h:90,
                 from /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.1/include/ap_common.h:641,
                 from /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.1/include/ap_int.h:54,
                 from /home/user/Schreibtisch/BA/lstm-pynq/lstm/src/library/host/input_handling.hpp:55,
                 from /home/user/Schreibtisch/BA/lstm-pynq/lstm/src/library/host/input_handling.cpp:34:
/opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.1/include/hls_fpo.h:65:2: warning: #warning "Xilinx Floating Point Operator IP core does not provide simulation models for ARM architecture.  Automatically defining HLS_NO_XIL_FPO_LIB in order to avoid this library dependency, although bit-accurate simulation of some functions is no longer possible.  You can make this warning go away by adding this define yourself before including any other files." [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Xilinx Floating Point Operator IP core does not provide simulation models for ARM architecture.  Automatically defining HLS_NO_XIL_FPO_LIB in order to avoid this library dependency, although bit-accurate simulation of some functions is no longer possible.  You can make this warning go away by adding this define yourself before including any other files."
  ^~~~~~~
/tmp/ccGImJzE.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccGImJzE.s:23684: Error: conditional branch out of range
/tmp/ccGImJzE.s:23688: Error: conditional branch out of range
CMakeFiles/hw-asr-W2A2-ocr-pynq.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/hw-asr-W2A2-ocr-pynq.dir/library/host/input_handling.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hw-asr-W2A2-ocr-pynq.dir/library/host/input_handling.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/hw-asr-W2A2-ocr-pynq.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hw-asr-W2A2-ocr-pynq.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm especially puzzled by the two Assembler messages that cause the error (conditional branch out of range).

Since I don't really know why this error occurs, it's hard to tell which other information to provide here. Running `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --version` gives

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I hope someone can give me an idea of why this error occurs or what I can do to debug it. I am more than happy to provide any additional information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you provide a minimalist example? or give the project repository? the problem can may be come from a too long code in a if or a switch

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Will come back to you in a bit, hopefully with a minimalist example that reproduces the error – I don't think there's any switches in the code, but there might be long if-statements. I'll have a look.